# How dynamically aligning text on website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I recently looked at google drive's website and I notice how perfectly their text adjust to when the browser window changes. I just wanted to all that affect to my website.

For now I am struggling with it. I tried using the css justify but that does not do the trick. Any suggestion or tips that I could use. Thanks

Here is the website I was looking at! https://www.google.com/drive/

This is what is frustrating me, there is so much space between some words. Whereas in google website it is perfect. Any help will be very much appreciated Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Sorry, Please click the "image description here" to view the photo. Also, I am not looking for specific answers or code, just want to know what tools I will need to achieve this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for responsive design use bootstrap plugin and its classes in your UI.
[refer link](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but I align or justify text using bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

By using rem or em in your website design you can get automatic adjustable text.

Watch this video to learn it.

[Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHf3aQz50jQ)

Answer (score 0):

This is called a "Responsive Design". Although you can write the CSS yourself to accomplish this, you can use an existing CSS framework like Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com) or Foundation (http://foundation.zurb.com/).

A site that has a tutorial on how to do this yourself: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp